# Sinatra via rackup does not like inline templates

Tags: templates, sinatra, rackup

When calling sinatra itself, `$ ruby tubemp.rb` works. But via `rackup` it does not. The application, somehow cannot find the inline templates.

```
#config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
disable :run, :reload

require './tubemp.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

The error being returned is:

```
No such file or directory - /home/ber/Documenten/ET_tubemp/code/views/index.erb:
```

Relevant part from `tubemp.rb`

```
get '/' do
  #...
  erb :index
end

__END__
@@ layout
<html>
...
<%= yield %>

@@ index
Welcome!
```

Somehow, via rackup, it expects the views to live in actual view-files. I guess the rackup cannot handle the `__END__` token when including or so.

How should I deal with this, other then moving my templates into template files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Inline%20Templates):

> Inline templates defined in the source file that requires sinatra are automatically loaded. Call `enable :inline_templates` explicitly if you have inline templates in other source files.

In this case, when you use `rackup` it is your `config.ru` that calls `require 'sinatra'`, and Sinatra is looking in that file for any templates, and doesn’t find any. When you run your app file directly Sinatra searches `tubemp.rb` for the templates, and finds them.

To fix it, add

```
enable :inline_templates
```

to your `tubemp.rb` file (and any other source files that have inline templates).